Stochastic Gaussian Process vs Non-Stochastic Gaussian Process?
Lately I have observed that there are two types of Gaussian Processes:

Type 1: https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc411_f18/slides/lec20-slides.pdf
Type 2: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_process

Type 1 seems to be Non-Stochastic:

Non-Stochastic Gaussian Process: A  collection of random variable having a joint Gaussian distribution:
$$f(x) \sim GP(m(x), k(x, x'))$$


Here, $f(x)$ is a Gaussian Process where $m(x)$ is the mean function and $k(x, x')$ is the covariance function or kernel. The joint distribution of a set of observations $f = [f(x_1), ..., f(x_m)]^T$ is a multivariate normal distribution:
$$\begin{bmatrix} f(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ f(x_m) \end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix} m(x_1) \\ \vdots \\ m(x_m) \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} k(x_1, x_1) & \cdots & k(x_1, x_m) \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ k(x_m, x_1) & \cdots & k(x_m, x_m) \end{bmatrix}\right)$$
Type 2 seems to be Stochastic:

Gaussian Stochastic Process: A stochastic process where every finite collection of those random variables has a multivariate normal distribution:

$$\left\{X_t ; t\in T\right\}$$
Here, $X_t$ is a Gaussian Stochastic Process indexed by $t$ in the index set $T$. For every finite set of indices $t_1,\ldots,t_k$, the random variables $X_{t_1}, \ldots, X_{t_k}$ form a multivariate Gaussian random variable. The characteristic function of this joint distribution is given by:
$${ \mathbb E }\left[\exp\left(i \sum_{\ell=1}^k s_\ell \, \mathbf{X}_{t_\ell}\right)\right] = \exp \left(-\tfrac{1}{2} \sum_{\ell, j} \sigma_{\ell j} s_\ell s_j + i \sum_\ell \mu_\ell s_\ell\right)$$
In terms of the Gaussian Process, do Type 1 and Type 2 originate from the same source and are just variations on one another? Or these inherently two different things (and the only thing they have in common is the Gaussian Distribution)?
